# AlphaZero: which nodes visited during self-play?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search

Reading [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/from-scratch-implementation-of-alphazero-for-connect4-f73d4554002a) article was very helpful in getting a good understanding of the principles behind AlphaZero. Still, there is something I am not completely sure about.

Below is the author's `UCT_search` method, as can be consulted in his code on Github: https://github.com/plkmo/AlphaZero_Connect4/tree/master/src 
Here, `UCTNode.backup()` adds the net's `value_estimate` to all traversed nodes (see also this ['cheat sheet'](https://miro.medium.com/max/2200/1*0pn33bETjYOimWjlqDLLNw.png)).

```py
def UCT_search(game_state, num_reads,net,temp):
    root = UCTNode(game_state, move=None, parent=DummyNode())
    for i in range(num_reads):
        leaf = root.select_leaf()
        encoded_s = ed.encode_board(leaf.game); encoded_s = encoded_s.transpose(2,0,1)
        encoded_s = torch.from_numpy(encoded_s).float().cuda()
        child_priors, value_estimate = net(encoded_s)
        child_priors = child_priors.detach().cpu().numpy().reshape(-1); value_estimate = value_estimate.item()
        if leaf.game.check_winner() == True or leaf.game.actions() == []: # if somebody won or draw
            leaf.backup(value_estimate); continue
        leaf.expand(child_priors) # need to make sure valid moves
        leaf.backup(value_estimate)
    return root
```

This method seems to visit only the nodes directly connected to the root node. 
Yet, [The original DeepMind paper](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10045895/1/agz_unformatted_nature.pdf) (about AlphaGo Zero) says:

> Each simulation starts from the root state and iteratively selects
>   moves that maximise an upper confidence bound Q(s, a) + U(s, a), where
>   U(s, a) ∝ P(s, a)/(1 + N(s, a)), until a leaf node s' is encountered.

So instead, I would expect something like:

```py
def UCT_search():
    for i in range(num_reads):
        current_node = root
        while current_node.is_expanded:
            …
            current_node = current_node.select_leaf()
        current_node.backup(value_estimate)
```

<sup>(`UCTNode.is_expanded` is `False` if the node has not been visited yet (or is an end state, i.e. the end of the game)</sup>

Can you please explain why this is the case? Or am I overlooking something? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think as game-state is updated, the root node gets updated automatically. So, the new position would be the root that the function would start exploring from.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you mention is inside the [`select_leaf()` method](https://github.com/plkmo/AlphaZero_Connect4/blob/d4bcd24b54d4facf5333d90d0958cc2e72f994a9/src/MCTS_c4.py#L77), it selects the best leaf and not just the directly connected nodes